# What's the difference in office 2013 between skydrive storage and site file library

Tags: onedrive, office365, office-2013-preview

In web interface of office 2013 preview (enterprise) I am able to store files in skydrive and share them. Also, I am able to upload them to sharepoint section (in file library module).

This is a little messy. What are the differences?
How can I sync both locations with my comp?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to sync them? The cloud storage saves your files online, thus you don't need to use space on your own disk.

`SharePoint libraries are locations on a SharePoint site where you can store and manage the files that you share with team members. After you add files to the library, other people can read and edit them, depending on their permissions. SkyDrive, the free online storage service from Windows Live, enables you to access documents from almost anywhere, and to share them easily with anyone you grant permission to.`

Please see this link for more information: [click here](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/word/item/1e2e7fc9-28e8-44e9-a11f-66f38d8416ce)